# Ror: cancancan hide index page on specific users type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

I got an issue with [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem and inherited tables on Ruby on rails.
My account model has multiple inherited models `Teacher < Account`, `Director < Account` which have different abilities.

Here are my rules: "in ability.rb"

```
if account.director?
  can :manage, Account, profile: [ :teacher, :director ]
end

if account.teacher?
  can :manage, Account, profile: [ :teacher ]
end
```

My route file looks like:

```
resources :directors, controller: :accounts, profile: :director
resources :teachers, controller: :accounts, profile: :teacher
```

When I'm logged in as a teacher and I go to /directors (index page), Cancan should raise a Unauthorized::AccessDenied message instead of displaying the directors page.

I probably missed something in the doc. Is someone could enlighten me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Accouding to this:

```
can :read, Project, :active => true, :user_id => user.id
```

Something like that inside Ability class should match Rails STI sub-class:

```
can :manage, Account, type: 'Teacher'
```